# Tabbed Chat Application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tabs

I am working on a standalone chat application for a third party network.  I am able to log in and send and receive messages between users fine.  What I am stuck on is having multiple tabs, each tab communicating with a certain user.

I have a form with a list of users and a tab control that has a main area for initiating commands, such as changing nickname and setting your status.  To start a chat, the user would double click on a user in the user list, and a new tab would be opened.  This is where I get stuck.

I believe I am on the right track with this, but don't know where to go next.  I use a UserControl with a tab control to make a TabPage for the new chat session.

**ChatPage.cs:**

```
public partial class ChatPage : UserControl
{
    public static string id;
    public ChatPage (string name, string idd)
    {
        id = idd;
        InitializeComponent ();
        this.friendPage.Text = name;
        this.friendBox.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler (friendBox_KeyDown);
    }

    public void friendBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            switch (this.friendBox.Text) {
                default:
                    // Code for sending the chat message
                    break;
            }
            this.friendBox.Clear ();
        }
    }
}
```

And to open the tab, I do this in the main form:

**Main.cs**

```
private void NewTab (string name, SteamID id)
{
    var userControl = new ChatPage (name, id);

    tabControl1.TabPages.Add (userControl.tabControl1.TabPages[0]);
}
```

This works fine as long as I am only communicating with one user.

However, when I open a session with a different user, the controls in all of the pages, not just the new one, are changed to reflect the newly created session.  Messages sent or received in any of the tabs are sent to/from the user who's session was most recently created.

I'm looking for a way to have multiple tabs open, and have each one be for a different user.

I've looked around, and have not found a solution.  I am quite stumped.

Comment: Looks like there is a reference somewhere that isn't being updated.  Is the tab contents just holding two textboxes?  One for the chat, and another to enter your chat to send; or is it only one textbox with the chat, and the textbox to enter your chat shared between the tabs?

Comment: @justderb There is a text box on each tab to enter a message, and a rich text box for the messages coming in on each page as well.

Comment: @justderb Ok.  What I've done is changed the name of the boxes to the id of the user I am sending/receiving messages from.  When sending one, I get the id from the text box and use that to send the message.  It works, but is this really how I should be doing it?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see what `userControl.tabControl1.TabPages[0]` is. But you usually should add tab pages and controls on them in a way like this:

```
private void NewTab (string name, SteamID id)
{
    var userControl = new ChatPage (name, id);

    TabPage newTab = new TabPage(name);
    newTab.Controls.Add(userControl);

    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(newTab);
}
```